# Library to Create a JSONObject in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, java, .net, json, object

I am looking for a JSON library which is able to do the following:

**PC 1**

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "mkyong.com");
obj.put("age", new Integer(100));
```

**PC 2**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
System.out.println(name);

long age = (Long) jsonObject.get("age");
System.out.println(age);
```

As you can see, there was no need to create a class in order to send the name and age value pairs.  Now, this code is in Java.  Is there a library in .NET which does this?  I checked the documentation for JSON.NET, however it appears that it does not offer the use of a JSONobject where we can add value pairs.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.Name = "mkyong.com";
jsonObject.Age = 100;
var json = jsonObject.ToString();
```

output:

```
{
    "Name": "mkyong.com",
    "Age": 100
}
```

or without `dynamic`

```
JObject jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject["Name"] = "mkyong.com";
jsonObject["Age"] = 100;
var json = jsonObject.ToString();
```

You can even make use of anonymous classes

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Name="mkyong.com", Age=100 });
```